# Script Shell Extract String In the middle

Tags: shell, script

```
#!/bin/sh
lineversion="/tmp/g-9.n.gggg1000.fr-worker1.V.2.tar.bz2"
```

My question: how can I extract

```
 g-9.n.gggg1000.fr
```

from

```
$lineversion
```

in another variable?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the method depends on what you know about the format of the string BEFORE it appears.

This can be one solution, but slight changes of the input can cause it to fail:

```
lv=${lineversion##*/}; lv=${lv%-*}; echo $lv
```

On the other hand, beware of spaces around = in assignments!